# Any advice on Implementing an Oauth Provider with AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-architecture

I currently have a functional `Oauth Authentication Provider` implemented with `Spring Security Oauth` running on an `AWS ECS cluster`, but I would like to come up with a `server-less` implementation using `AWS Lambda` with [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model).  I am aware that there are wonderful SaaS providers such as `Auth0`, but the price for the thousands of user accounts we will require is prohibitively expensive.

I have discovered [danilop/LambdaAuth](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth), which is useful, but not `OAuth`.  For now, I only require a `client_credentials` grant, which seems very simple.  But I would like to be able to leverage some `library` which will make it easier to implement more grants and flows for the future.  I have investigated `python's` [oauth2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2) and [oauthlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauthlib) libraries, but the documentation appears to be useless for my requirements.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: What is the purpose of writing your oauth provider? is it for authentication or authorized access(authorization) to resources?

Comment: Authentication.  I've updated the question to be more specific.